# Preserve ordering of Python's itertools.product

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I want to find all the combinations of two lists using `itertools`'s product function:

```
from itertools import product
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
years = ['2021', '2022']
list(product(*[months, years]))
```

This outputs

```
 [('January', '2021'), ('January', '2022'), ('February', '2021'), ('February', '2022'), ('March', '2021'), ('March', '2022'), ('April', '2021'),
```

and so on. Is it possible to preserve the order of the `months` list? I also want to convert the tuples to strings where the `months` and `years` elements are separated by `_`.

This is what I'm aiming to get:

```
['January_2021', 'February_2021', 'March_2021', 'April_2021', ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just swap the lists in `itertools.product`:

```py
out = [f"{m}_{y}" for y, m in product(*[years, months])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "January_2021",
    "February_2021",
    "March_2021",
    "April_2021",
    "May_2021",
    "June_2021",
    "July_2021",
    "August_2021",
    "September_2021",
    "October_2021",
    "November_2021",
    "December_2021",
    "January_2022",
    "February_2022",
    "March_2022",
    "April_2022",
    "May_2022",
    "June_2022",
    "July_2022",
    "August_2022",
    "September_2022",
    "October_2022",
    "November_2022",
    "December_2022",
]
```

Comment: Could also replace `product(*[years, months])` with `product(years, months)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Good point... Perhaps we all just copied the example from the question :) But `product(years, months)` is more correct.

Comment: Yeah I realized that afterwards and rephrased. The OP also has decent Python reputation. Odd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to swap the order of the arguments to `product()`, and then do a little string manipulation on each tuple that's produced:

```py
list('_'.join([month, year]) for year, month in product(*[years, months]))
```

This outputs:

```py
['January_2021', 'February_2021', 'March_2021', 'April_2021', 'May_2021', 'June_2021', 'July_2021', 'August_2021', 'September_2021', 'October_2021', 'November_2021', 'December_2021', 'January_2022', 'February_2022', 'March_2022', 'April_2022', 'May_2022', 'June_2022', 'July_2022', 'August_2022', 'September_2022', 'October_2022', 'November_2022', 'December_2022']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map `str.format`:

```py
out = list(map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format, product(*[years, months])))
```

Output:

```py
['January_2021', 'February_2021', 'March_2021', 'April_2021', 'May_2021', 'June_2021', 
 'July_2021', 'August_2021', 'September_2021', 'October_2021', 'November_2021', 'December_2021', 
 'January_2022', 'February_2022', 'March_2022', 'April_2022', 'May_2022', 'June_2022', 'July_2022', 
 'August_2022', 'September_2022', 'October_2022', 'November_2022', 'December_2022']
```

Comment: or `list(starmap("{}_{}".format, product(*[years, months])))` :) +1

Comment: @AndrejKesely that's a really nice option as well.